# Using AddDistributedSqlServerCache with Managed Service Identity

Tags: asp.net, azure, access-token, azure-ad-msal, distributed-caching

Hi I have a question about using the SQL backed distributed cache as described in here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/how-to/token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnet

The code I'm using look like this:

```
 // SQL Server token cache
 app.AddDistributedTokenCache(services =>
 {
  services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
  {
   // Requires to reference Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer
   options.ConnectionString = @"...connection string goes here...";
   options.SchemaName = "dbo";
   options.TableName = "TestCache";
   options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
  });
 });
```

When I do the local testing using the following connection string, it works fine:
`"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DefaultDb;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"`

But when I switch to the connection string for Azure SQL:
`"Data Source=some.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=DefaultDb;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"`

I get the following exception:
`Message  "Login failed for user ''." string Source  "Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider"`

My hunch is I might have to set the AccessToken like other part of our code does because we use Manage service identity when calling Azure SQL:

```
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
   connection.AccessToken = accessToken;
```

The problem is SqlServerCacheOptions does not have a property that allows you to set the AccessToken. My question is how can I use the distributed SQL backed cache on an ASP.NET app that uses Azure SQL with Managed service identity.

Comment: Use SQL Auth or one of the AAD ServicePrincipalAuth.  Either one can be configured in the connection string.